Running ssh command in Jenkins pipeline hangs
I have a Jenkins agent running on Windows machine with openssh for Windows installed. My pipeline looks like this:
stage('Run ssh command') {
    agent {
        label 'windows-agent'
    }
    steps {
        script {
            bat 'ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -vv -i key.pem some-user@some-host some-command'
        }
    }
}

However the stage hangs when executing ssh. What's more the logs are not printed properly for some reason.
I added the -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no to ensure ssh will not prompt for the password. The connection is never established (I checked on the server side).
The same command run from cmd.exe under the same user that is running Jenkins jobs works perfectly fine.
If I remove -i key.pem to ensure the command fails it sill hangs. I also experimented with -T or -tt but the result is the same.
This is the Jenkins console output:
[2024-07-17T09:17:15.654Z] OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[2024-07-17T09:17:15.654Z] debug2: resolving "some-host" port 22
[2024-07-17T09:17:15.654Z] ode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -vv -i key.pem some-user@some-host some-command

<hangs here forever>

As you can see the logs from ssh are not complete, I would expect multiple lines of debug data.
I'm using Jenkins 2.462.
Any ideas how to troubleshoot?
Update
I run multiple more tests and use tools like Process Monitor from Sysinternals. What I observed that ssh is able to connect to the server but it hangs either after writing to standard output (when -vvv is used) or after writing data to standard output if -vvv is not used. It looks like first few write operations are fine but later the program hangs.
I realized git process also uses ssh to pull the code and it works fine. So instead of using ssh client from OpenSSH package for Windows (located in C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe) I used ssh client from Git package for Windows (located in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe). This binary works completely fine and I'm not experiencing any issues.
I still don't know what was the root cause however.But my immediate problem is resolved.

How are you starting the jenkins agent ? eg, jnlp, scheduled task   or some other means ?

I use openssh for windows and I select Launch agent via SSH. This allows to ssh to a Windows machine and get the access to cmd.exe. When I connect manually using ssh to agent machine using the same credentials as I use in Jenkins I can execute the command with no issues. Everything else in the whole pipeline, which I did not include in the post (building software, running unit tests, uploading artifacts to artifactory, running some custom git pull) works fine on this agent. The only problem seems to be with calling ssh)

There are more vs you can add. I think -vvvv is the max. See if it gives you more output

Thanks for the hint, but it did not help. Still only one line of debug output is captured and it's nothing that brings any information to the problem.

@chicken-rice  indeed that was the answer i was looking for - other mechanisms could cause (other sort) issues in Windows. Next i'd disable usage of ssh-agent and make sure the private key does not require password for using it.  Or ensure the ssh-agent is running, accessible for the jenkins process and the key is added to it. Jenkins will strip quite a lot of environment variables when it starts and if windows ssh-agent relies on finding the ssh-agent via env, it could be the reason. Maybe

I don't use ssh-agent. While testing I tried to remove anything that could be impacting the observed behavior. So I'm trying simply to run ssh -o BatchMode=yes -vv some-user@some-host some-command. Since I'm not providing the key and I enabled BatchMode ssh should simply print the error and exit (that's what I observe when running it from the cmd.exe, both when starting cmd.exe from Windows GUI and when connecting to cmd.exe over openssh for Windows). Yet it still hangs.

I found a way to make it work, updated the original post.
